Copy historical content from "Show history" into the clipboard?
In the following screenshot it is my intention to copy the differing content on the left panel to the clipboard [for later incorporation into the current version.  I do not want to overwrite/replace the current content on the right but rather will have two somewhat different versions of that method.
When I try to select the green content on the left it is not possible to do so: instead the dialog pops up as shown

Cannot find declaration to go to

How can I simply copy the content on the left into the clipboard?
In case it matters I am on MacOS Sonoma 14.5 and have Pycharm Professional 2024.1.4


Are you sure you used the correct shortcut? Text in diff views are always freely selectable/copyable.

I can not get to select the text [as described]: so copying it is a later step. There is nothing to copy yet.

There's no context action (right-click on Windows) to copy the text in PyCharm's diff viewer. What works is selecting with the cursor/mouse and using the keyboard Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V. The fact that you have a pop-up saying "cannot find declaration" suggests you somehow lost focus on the window because that functionality isn't even available in my diff, but whatever works to select the text should allow copy-pasting using the keyboard shortcuts.

@bad_coder.  You are on to something here.  I was doing my normal process of showing diff - but apparently Pycharm has gotten fixated on some syntax thing - and doesn't realize that I'm in the middle of a diff dialog. That's a tiny bug on their end.   There should be a workaround however: to simply ensure that the code in the selection is valid before running diff.  Would you care to make this an answer?  btw Nice to see you dropping by!  You've answered a bunch of these questions over the years: much appreciated.

@WestCoastProjects good to see you too! I'm insanely overworked this July, I hope to get some respite this week to gather my thoughts and a convert a couple of comments to proper answers that can be posted. Sorry I haven't done so already but it's been hectic for me lately...
